# Working with unicode keys in a python dictionary

Tags: python, twitter, dictionary, unicode

I am learning about the Twitter API using Python 2.7.x. I've saved a number of random tweets and I am trying to process them. Each tweet is converted to a dictionary with json.loads and all the dictionaries are part of a list.

Given a single tweet, I want to be able to extract certain fields from the dictionary. The keys are all unicode strings. If I iterate through the keys in a loop, I have no trouble printing the values:

```
for i in tweet.keys():
    print i, tweet[i]
```

So the loop above works fine, but I have had no luck figuring out how to manually specify  key. "u'text'" is the key for the actual tweet content (the user's actual post). If I try to print tweet['text'], I get a KeyError. I naively tried tweet[u'text'] but that fails with a KeyError too.

I guess I am curious about the difference between what the loop is doing as it steps through tweet.keys() vs. what I am doing when manually I specifying a key. Note that if I print the value of i in the loop above, the key name is printed, but without the unicode wrapping. When the key is "u'text'", the value of i is just 'text', or at least that is what is printed to the terminal.

Comment: Why not doing for key, elem in testDict.items():
    print key, elem

Comment: Since `'text' == u'text'` (python implicitly encodes / decodes as needed here), it simply means *you don't have that key* in your dictionary.

Comment: The difference then must be that you are looking *at a different dictionary*. One that does **not** have a `'text'` key.

Comment: Note to other readers, this is different in python3, where comparison `b'text' != 'text'` is not even allowed

Comment: @wim: but no unicode string would ever be displayed with the `u` prefix either.

Comment: Actually it is perfectly allowed to have the u prefix in py3 source code.

Comment: Hm, if the tweets are in a list, how about `tweet[i]['text']` in your loop?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You put me on the right track. I am processing a list of tweets and you are correct: some of them do not have a 'text' element, which I knew but obviously had my head up my arse. Not seeing the forest for the trees here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shep: then use the `'text' in tweet` membership test as shown in my answer, or use `tweet.get('text')` to get a default if the value is not present, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Done, thanks. I'm filtering out all the stuff I'm not interested in by checking for the presence of a 'text' element, 'lang' element, and where tweet['lang'] == 'en' (need English language tweets only for what I am working on).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python 2 handles translation between `str` and `unicode` keys transparently for you, provided the text can be encoded to ASCII:

```
>>> d = {u'text': u'Foo'}
>>> d.keys()
[u'text']
>>> 'text' in d
True
>>> u'text' in d
True
>>> d['text']
u'Foo'
>>> d[u'text']
u'Foo'
```

This means that if you get a `KeyError` for `tweet['text']`, then *that dictionary has no such key*.

Comment: In my case I was iterating through a list of random tweets pulled from the twitter stream. I was only interested in actual posted and original messages, not re-tweets, other non-tweet posts, etc., but I was not filtering these out. Cheers to @MartijnPieters for clearing my head.

Comment: The last statement is confusing, or is it still constrained by **provided the text can be encoded to ASCII**. Given `d = {u"ä": 1}` you get a key error with `d["ä"]` and the other way around. My conclusion would be: If you don't know if the query value is ASCII encodable, you have to convert both key and query value to either `str` or `unicode` (if you want them to match).

Comment: @bluenote10: `'text'` **is** ASCII. Not all their data contains the key, however.

Comment: @bluenote10: note that my answer *begins* with *provided the text can be encoded to ASCII:*

Comment: @bluenote10: last but not least, the issue is that the OP assumed that all of the dictionaries they had saved would have a `text` key, then misinterpreted the exception without revisiting their assumption.

Comment: All I wanted to say is that the first and last sentence confused me. To me it sounded like: If you get a `KeyError` for `"ä"` you can be sure that there is neither a key `"ä"` nor the key `u"ä"`, which is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {u'text': u'Foo'}
>>> print "d:{text}".format(**d)
d:Foo
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.