# How to get tweet from json tweets

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying print what I think is the tweet portion of a tweet data. I am getting "KeyError" for the text key in the dictionary.

```
import json

with open('tweets.json','rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        json_data = json.loads(line)
        print json_data[u'text']
        print '\n\n'
```

This is some of the data (truncated) I'm trying to get the text key from:

```
{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'\u3053\u308c\u3001\u3053\u308c\uff01\uff01\uff01\n\u307e\u3058\u306750\',
```

Comment: Are you sure this is how your code looks like currently? Because now you are missing some stuff in the line `encoded_string = json_data[u'`. Probably you meant it to be `encoded_string = json_data[u'text']`.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the post.

Comment: I get the following error: KeyError: u'text'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532229/working-with-unicode-keys-in-a-python-dictionary See this, might be that some of the lines do not have the text-field.

Comment: Thank you Teemu. That post helped. I was able to use an if statement to test for the presence of the text key.

Comment: Teemu, how do I mark your post as an answer?

Comment: You can not, but don't worry about it :) Might be even better to close this question as a duplicate to the one I linked.