# Accessing Unicode Values in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode

I have a dictionary full of unicode keys/values due to importing JSON through json.loads().

```
dictionaryName = {u'keyName' : u'valueName'}
```

I'm trying to access values inside the dictionary as follows:

```
accessValueName = dictionaryName.get('keyName')
```

This returns None, assumedly because it is looking for the String 'keyName' and the list is full of unicode values. I tried sticking a 'u' in front of my keyName when making the call, but it still returns none.

```
accessValueName = dictionaryName.get(u'keyName')
```

I also found several seemingly outdated methods to convert the entire dictionary to string values instead of unicode, however, they did not work, and I am not sure that I need the entire thing converted.

How can I either convert the entire dictionary from Unicode to String or just access the values using the keyname?

EDIT:

I just realized that I was trying to access a value from a nested dictionary that I did not notice was nested.

The solution is indeed:

```
accessValueName = dictionaryName.get('keyName')
```

Comment: `accessValueName = dictionaryName.get('keyName')` should work just fine, with or without `u`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532229/working-with-unicode-keys-in-a-python-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries store values in a hash table using the hash values of the object.

```
print(hash(u"example"))
print(hash("example"))
```

Yields the same result. Therefore the same dictionary value should be accessible with both.

Comment: OP just edited stating it was a non reproducible mistake ;)

Comment: @RafaelC Just saw that, I leave the answer here if someone later comes here reading the title, and needs such knowledge.

Comment: Two *different* values can have the same hash, however.  If you are using Python 3, `u'example'` and `'example'` are two syntaxes for the same Unicode string. In Python 2, the types are different, but ASCII byte strings and ASCII unicode strings happen to have the same hash, and Python will implicitly convert from one to the other for comparison.  Python 3 wouldn't do that.